# how get the value of data info when selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how get value of data-info (@Libelle) in javascript when selected option

```
<select id="selectVal">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
</select>
<div data-info="@Libelle"></div>

<script>
...
</script>
```

Comment: based on what ?

Comment: The value doesn't change when the option is selected, so why not just read it in to a variable once on page load and access that variable when the selected option changes?

Answer (score 1):

Use a change event, use `data()` to get the value:

```
$('#selectVal').change(function() {
 var info =  $('[data-info]').data('info');
 alert(info);
});
```

Comment: if i have more of div like : `<div data-info="@Libelle"></div>` `<div data-info="@Libelle"></div>` `<div data-info="@Libelle"></div>` how verify if date-info equals option selected

Comment: @faycelzouaoui use a loop